# Query - Trying to SUM one field based on content of another field

Tags: sql, ms-access

**Table:**

```
DayOfWeek           Enrollments
Monday                 35
Monday                 12
Saturday               25
Tuesday                15
Monday                  9
Tuesday                15
```

Basically I'm trying to sum the total enrolments for each day.

so the Output will look like:

```
DayOfWeek           Enrollments
Monday                 56
Saturday               25
Tuesday                30
```

I've spent around 4 hours trying to work this out trying many many different ways but no luck.

The problem I'm having is i can count how many enrollments for each day but can't have it aligned with the correct day when i run the query e.g. I want The total to be on the same line as the day it was calculated from. (I hope that is clear enough)

Comment: SELECT DayOfWeek, SUM(Enrollments) AS Enrollments FROM x GROUP BY DayOfWeek

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Group by `DayOfWeek`, and ask for the sum of `Enrollments` within each group.  The SQL will look like this.

```
SELECT DayOfWeek, Sum(Enrollments) AS SumOfEnrollments
FROM YourTable
GROUP BY DayOfWeek;
```

If you're using the Access query designer to create this, select your fields, then click the symbol for "Totals" query (Greek character sigma).  In the "Total:" row of the design grid, select Group By and Sum for the appropriate fields.

Comment: Wow, Soo simple, Thanks heaps that is very very easier and simpler to the code i had...